# Discord.py AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i am trying to make my bot send a message in my log channel whenever someone leave or join the server but i am getting the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'` in my console.
I have already tried many solutions i found on StackOverflow and other websites but nothing seems to work in my case.

Here is my code:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
   logChannel = bot.get_channel(id=myLogChannelIdHere)
   embed = discord.Embed(
      title= "** Un membre est parti**",
      description = f"${member} a quitté le serveur",
      color=0xda291c,
      set_thumbnail = member.avatar_url,
      )
   embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
   await logChannel.send(embed=embed)
```

The thing i don't understand is that i have the exact same thing in other event like for my on_ready event (When my bot come online it send a message in my log channel) and it work perfectly

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
   logChannel = bot.get_channel(id=myLogChannelIdHere)
   await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=""))
   await logChannel.send("Le bot est en ligne")
   print(bot.user.name + " est en ligne")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the id has been entered correctly in the code?

Comment: Yes of course. In my real code it look like this: ```logChannel = bot.get_channel(id=966xxxx014)```
x are other numbers of course

Comment: It might not be fully cached (in which case use `fetch` instead). But also I believe you're not allowed to specify keyword arguments for that anymore. Do `bot.get_channel(12345)` without the `id=` kwarg.

Comment: Sadly, with or without the id=123456789 or fetch instead of get it still doesn't work. I also asked for help on some others forum and after spending time trying to find the issue no solutions have been found yet. But thanks alot for trying to help me!

Answer (score -1):

Try to first print out what get_channel returns because if get_channel can't find a channel it will return None.

Try it out by hardcoding an int  in bot.get_channel()

and see what it returns

Also check so the Bot actually can see that channel and write to it.

I tried it out on my own bot and it works fine for me.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psCGI.png)

[Copy the text channel ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51KYH.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seIgb.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
First i did ```print(bot.get_channel(int(966799968889340014)))``` as you told me to and it return me the channel name so i guess its okay here.
Second yes the bot can write in this channel because usually its here that my bot log edited and deleted messages, its just after that i had tried to implement this event that everything started to bug

Answer (score -1):

It seems like your `logChannel = bot.get_channel(id=myLogChannelIdHere)` isn't actually catching the channel, this could happen for a couple of reasons.

The value stored in `myLogChannelIdHere` is either not a valid channel id that the bot can see, or it is not an Integer. If it's a string, wrapping `int()` around it will solve it.

One other point may or may not be relevant, when I use `get_channel` I don't specify the `id=` parameter, I just pop the channel id straight in.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply and sorry for my lately one. I have done what you told me to do```logChannel = bot.get_channel(id=channelid)``` is now ```logChannel = bot.get_channel(int(channelid))```and nothing changed. And the worst thing is that i have no more error in my console :/
And yes it is catching the channel because when my bot start it does send a message in the channel ( this is non sense ). But thanks for your reply i appreciate

Answer (score -1):

```py
import discord
from discord import Member
from discord.utils import get
```

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member:Member):
    if member.bot:
        guild:discord.Guild = member.guild
        role = guild.get_role(config.botRoleID)
        channel:discord.TextChannel = guild.get_channel(YOUR_CHANNEL_ID)
        await member.add_roles(role)
        await channel.send(f'Set Bot role to "{member.display_name}" ')
```